# How to split the sentence in edit text field and drag & drop the splitted words in another fields?

Tags: android

I am scanning the visiting cards and able to get the objects successfully in edit text fields like in image shown below[image: Below the cropped image the sentences which should be splitted are there I want to split them individually and drag & drop them in another field]

Below the cropped image the sentences which should be splitted are there I want to split them individually and drag & drop them in another field?

Answer (score 0):

you can split a string to a String array by

```
String testString="this is a test";
String[] stringArray=testString.split(" ");
```

in your case you need the new line to do the spliting, so use `.split("\n")`
then you can copy this to an other location
`textbox.setText=stringArray[1];`

Comment: I want to drag and drop the selected splited word to another edit text field.

Comment: what do you mean to "drag & drop" it? you are programming it, right? you cant drag anything. you can copy a cell of the string array to someplace else. see updated answer